# Why JavaFx gives error on width of HBox

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am new learner for JavaFx Technology , I was given the width to HBox in fxml file and it gives me error , Can anyone tell me why this happen ?

```
 <HBox width="200"></HBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Any attribute you use must correspond to a property with a corresponding public `set...(...)` method. There is no writable property called `width` (i.e. there is no public `setWidth(...)` method) defined in `HBox`. See the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html) for the properties and methods that are defined.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute width is not valid for HBox.  I think the attribute you are looking for is **prefWidth** as in.

```
<HBox prefHeight="200" />
```

If you use JavaFX Scene Builder to create your fxml then it will allow you to do it all graphically and put in all the correct attributes for you.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html

Hope this helps.